# How to remove extra spaces between the view and the outline border of it in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

[image: screenshot of my Android studio editor]

How can i get rid of these spaces that i marked with red ?
I tried to set padding to zero and nothing changes

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/req_delete_btn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:text="Delete"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/req_pp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/req_accept_btn"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/req_name" />
```

Note: `android:layout_width="0dp"` because it has constraints with another button and it expands with it.

Full xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/req_pp"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/default_pp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/req_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/req_pp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/req_pp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/req_accept_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:text="Accept"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/req_delete_btn"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/req_delete_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/req_delete_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:text="Delete"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/req_pp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/req_accept_btn"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/req_name" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Edited the post.

Comment: that is the `Button` boundaries. you can not remove them . you can make it overflow on other views but that space can not go away its just the button it self. do you understand me? if you have problem with the positioning we can help but that space will not go away that is not even space it's the button. if you want you can move your button to left but that space of boundaries will stick with it.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this, but now I want to align the left side of the Button with the left side of the TextView above but this space prevents this to happen. Any solutions? I could set padding to a negative value but it differs with larger and smaller screens

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

It's the shadow around the button in its background drawable. Create your own background and it will disappear. But keep in mind that when you setting android:background="@null" the button loses its touch animation, but it turns out that setting the background to anything at all fixes that border.

Also you can try to use: `<Button android:minHeight="0dp" android:minWidth="0dp"`

Or in your button's style:

```
<item name="android:minHeight">0dp</item>
<item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
```

Or try: `android:includeFontPadding="false"`

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the constrain of the `DELETE` button to `imageview`, same as `TextView` constrain so i can use margin to adjust the space .
now i've putted `android:layout_marginStart="14dp"` but you can change it to fit your need.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/req_pp"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/default_pp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/req_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="aaa gggg bbb"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/req_pp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/req_pp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/req_accept_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Accept"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/req_delete_btn"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/req_delete_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/req_delete_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:text="Delete"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/req_pp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/req_accept_btn"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/req_pp" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```